# performanceCounter Returns 0

Tags: c#, performancecounter

I know this question has been repeated so many times but when I follow what everyone suggests, it doesnt get me nowhere. I have the following code but when I try to get the values for the following counters I will be given 0 only:

```
private PerformanceCounter _AvgMS_Req = 
    new PerformanceCounter("Forefront TMG Web Proxy", "Average Milliseconds/request");
private PerformanceCounter _Avg_Req_Spd = 
    new PerformanceCounter("Forefront TMG Web Proxy", "Average request speed");

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _AvgMS_Req.NextValue();
    _Avg_Req_Spd.NextValue();
    Thread.Sleep(1000);

    Avg_MS_Req.Text = _AvgMS_Req.NextValue().ToString("0");
    Avg_Req_spd.Text = _Avg_Req_Spd.NextValue().ToString("0");
}
```

Before getting the values printed on the labels I have ran the code once but still it does not help. even if I remove these few lines from my code it will not help:

```
_AvgMS_Req.NextValue();
_Avg_Req_Spd.NextValue();
Thread.Sleep(1000);
```

Comment: Are you certain that any requests have been processed during the one second wait? Otherwise, 0 is the correct value.

Comment: Yes I am really sure of that... I have also tried increasing it to 5000 ms but still it didnt help...

Comment: If you are really sure then I guess my next suggestion to correlate with readings from Performance Monitor isn't useful after all.

Comment: Do you really see this possibility that there might be cases that there is no issue with our code but there is some problem in the background not allowing the code to read some performance counters?

Comment: @iSi, How did you solve this problem? I have the same problem :(